# How to play an audio frequency on the right earphone and a music on the left?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, audio, core-audio

I need to play an audio frequency (22KHz) on the right earphone and a music from the playlist on the left earphone from iPhone. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two audio files, one with the music, one with the audio frequency
2. Remove the right channel / left channel respecitvely
3. Play them simultaneously

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Yes I tought to do this however this way needs the audio file manipulation. I wanna the music chose be played only at the left channel, and at same moment the audio engine generates the 22KHz at the right channel. Maybe using auriotouch?

Comment: Sorry, now I understood your answer... Theres is a way to play two audio files at same time?

Comment: Yes, you can do so using the AVAudioPlayer class. Other options give you other possibilities. Here's a list: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6

Comment: Do you have an output proc where you get your audio from a buffer or the file?